# in fright & with fright

Tags: prepositions

I'm quite confused by the usage of prep., so may I ask when I should use "in" or "with", since I read some sentences  below

1. The birds smashed into the top of their cages **in fright**.
2. The steam pipes rattled suddenly, and Franklin jumped **with fright**.
   He was shaking **with fright**.

" **In fright", " with fright"**, what's the difference between them, can they be replaced by each other? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are basically the same. You could argue that in some cases one may seem more natural but that depends on style and tone.

Based purely on instinct (and I can't find a good source):

- "*with fright*" means that being frightened is the cause of an action
- "*in fright*" describes an activity done in a state of being frightened

For example:

- "He ran away *with fright*": he was so frightened that he ran away
- "He ran away *in fright*": he ran away and he was frightened when doing it

But as noted, this is missing a citation to an authoritative source.

Comment: I did upvote, but your answer would be even better if you provided some reference.

Comment: 'Petrified with fear/fright': still causative, but here causing a stste. You could trawl through the first n Google hits for "in fright" and "with fright" and after discarding irrelevant ("there is a silent _g_ in _fright_" etc) and non-overt examples, give proportions corresponding to the causative and purely depictive cases respectively.

Comment: Thanks for all your explainations